# How to escape Backslash in Javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, escaping

I know question is asked many times, i gone through with all the questions. but none of them is helping my situation. I have a object literal, for one of the property i assign some string which has backslash charecter, but while reading the property the backslash is getting truncated.

I want to use this object literal in JSON.Stringify method. as per JSON, backslash are not allowed. we need to escape it. is there any way ?

i cant modify the data to add an extra backslash, because data is coming from the server. 'localhost\sqlserver'. after that i need to replace it.

Object literal

```
var data={
    s:'localhost\sqlserver'
}


function replaceToUpper(value) { 
    return   value.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n") 
                                      .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'") 
                                      .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&") 
                                      .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r") 
                                      .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t") 
                                      .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b") 
                                      .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f"); 
}
```

//reading the data

```
alert(replaceToUpper(data.s));
```

attempt 2 :

```
var values =JSON.stringify(data); // here that backslash getting trucunated
```

what do i missing here.   check the fiddle [Object Literal with Backslash](http://jsfiddle.net/WgANT/2/)

**i cant modify the data to add an extra backslash, because data is coming from the server. 'localhost\sqlserver'. after that i need to replace it. I know adding extra blackslash would help me. but i cant modify the data.**

Comment: i just concentrating the backslash escaping. i don't know why it's not working

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because i have changed the data layer such that it escapes the data. as question does not help any other people. pls close it

Answer (score 2):

use \\ to escape \

var data = {
    s: 'localhost\\sqlserver'}

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

Answer (score 1):

it is a string literal where `\` is an escape character so if you want to use a `\` as it is then you need to escape it with another `\` like `\\`

```
'localhost\\sqlserver'
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7L4mu/)

Comment: i cant modify the data, data is coming from the server. 'localhost\sqlserver'. after that i need to replace it. I know this by adding extra backslash. i want to replace it from javascript. not by manually

Comment: @Ravi then I don't think you can do much as the string will escape `\`... try to type `'localhost\sqlserver'` in the browser console the `\` is already escaped

Answer (score 1):

before save JSON as string into db or somethis use REGEX

```
JSON.stringify(drivers).replace(/"/g, '\\"')
```