# Set \ as string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I set a \ as a string in JavaScript I am using it like this

```
Var x = {"\":"some value"}
```

But it's says that that is illegal, so then I tried  it like '\' this but still the same error happened.

Comment: check out escape characters in JavaScript...

Comment: Escaping a backslash `\\` is useful but it's generally bad practice to name an object property that.

Comment: [How to escape Backslash in Javascript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20207501/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use escaping characters so add one more \ it will be escaped and become a string like this `var x = {"\\":"some value"}`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an other slash '\' before it.