# How To escape backslash in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I send a POST Request with JSON Objet in body to an application which is expecting this kind of value:

```
{
   "input": {
      "queryFilter": "mail eq \"john.doe@foo.de\""
   }
}
```

The Request works fine and I get a response 200.

Then I want to send the same Request via UI/Form and try to pass it as JSON Object as following:

```
input: {
    queryFilter: '"mail eq \"' + mail + '\" "'
}
```

Which ends in: 
`{input: {queryFilter: ""mail eq "john.doe@foo.de" ""}}`

This is syntactically not correct and not as the working JSON via Postman.
Also trying it as:

```
input: {
    queryFilter: {
       mail: mail
    }
}
```

didn't help.

I have been checking some postings like: [How to escape Backslash in Javascript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207501/how-to-escape-backslash-in-javascript-object-literal), but they look handling other kind of issues
So, how would it be possible to build the JSON Objet in the JavaScript file correctly so that it ends up exactly like the one working on Postman?

Comment: remove the double quote like : `input: {queryFilter: 'mail eq \"' + mail + '\" '}`

Comment: It ends up as: `queryFilter:"mail eq "john.doe@foo.de" "` which is not expected by the application. It should keep the backslashes. e.g. `"queryFilter": "mail eq \"john.doe@foo.de\""`. Maybe the titel of my question isn't 100% correct for the issue.

Comment: In your first example, there will be no backslash characters in the resulting string. The value of that `queryFilter` property will be the string `mail eq "john.doe@foo.de"`. The JavaScript parser itself will remove those backaslashes. Really, there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"; what you're building is a *JavaScript* object. When you serialize that with `JSON.stringify()` you'll get a valid JSON string.

Comment: Why are you building JSON using string concatenation? There's  a method specifically for building JSON: `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, true. It's being build as JavaScript Object, then being serialized to JSON. Just missed it when thinking/typing too quick. So, how to get a JSON Object at the end with a value containing backslash `/` and `"`. The Backend application is java based.

Comment: In that case you'd need to *double* the backslash in the JavaScript string value, just like you do when using a string to build a JavaScript regular expression that requires a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is not the double quote escaping with backslashes but the actual double quotes wrapping your json value.

Remove them like the following and you should be good to go !

```js
const mail = 'john@doe.com'
const obj = {
  input: {
    queryFilter: 'mail eq "' + mail + '" '
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quotes

Comment: @Andreas: As I said in my previous comment... I might have the wrong title for my issue. I want  to keep the backslashes in the json. The application is expecting this kind of value: `"queryFilter": "mail eq \"john.doe@foo.de\""`. Sry, My Bad.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({queryFilter: 'mail eq "john.doe@foo.de"'})` -> `"{"queryFilter":"mail eq \"john.doe@foo.de\""}"`

Comment: You are right @Andreas, I updated my answer with a snippet

Comment: @3Dos: looks correct your answer, but I'am facing a strange behavior. console.log putout the expected result, but when checking with Network, then: Request Payload I see: `input:{queryFilter: "mail eq "john.doe@foo.de" "}`. so, no backslashes which is not expected from the backend! I might update my question and add the function I'am using to clarify the workflow.

Comment: @k.vincent because it is maybe escaped but not actually exists in the string, try my answer if solves your problem with Network

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```js
var mail = "john.doe@foo.de";
var mailValue = "mail eq " + "\\\"" + mail + "\\\"";
var result = JSON.stringify(Object.create(null, {
  input: {
    value: {
      queryFilter: mailValue
    },
    enumerable: true
  }
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: remains same. I did update my Question to make it clearer. It might have to do with `form.builder.group()` function.